# Stripe create Subscribtion with Radar information (radar_session_id)

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

How can I make Stripe create Subscribtion with Radar information (radar_session_id) ?
For example when I make payment Intents - I add opntion radar_options' => ['session' => 'CODE'].

But in Create Subscribtion this paramert don't work

Solution. Exmaple Code

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for Radar Session attachment during Subscription creation currently. The recommendation instead would be to attach the Radar Session during *confirmation* of the [Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/confirm#confirm_setup_intent-payment_method_data-radar_options-session) or [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-payment_method_data-radar_options-session) generated by the Subscription object.

Alternatively, you can create and confirm a Setup Intent prior to creating the Subscription and you can then use the resulting `pm_xxx` ID for the recurring subscription payments. This is noted in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/radar-session#off-session):

> To send a Radar Session for off-session payments, which means completing the payment without the customer’s direct involvement, you need to attach a Radar Session when creating a Payment Method for your customer.

Comment: I use a Subscription with source card, how can I set radar information? because Your variants worked before I used a Subscription, but in both cases, I don't have ID, I have only an ID subscription.